# Are there any alternatives to shell_exec and proc_open in PHP?

Tags: php, exec, curl-multi

It seems like I can't use `shell_exec` or `proc_open` on my shared server.

The message I get when I try to use it is:

> Warning: shell_exec() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/georgee/public_html/admin/email.php on line 4

Are there any alternatives to these functions?

Comment: I need the function to run another script like so `php someotherfile.php`.

Comment: *(sidenote)* check the output of `phpinfo()` for the ini settings of `disable_classes` and `disable_functions` to see what is unavailable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to use this for async processing, for instance sending eMails in a separate process (hence the error in email.php). If so, please check if [cURL](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) is enabled. You can trigger your scripts through an HTTP request without waiting for the response.

Further reading:

- [Asynchronous/parallel HTTP requests using PHP multi_curl](http://www.jaisenmathai.com/blog/2008/05/29/asynchronous-parallel-http-requests-using-php-multi_curl/)
- [How to use curl_multi() without blocking](http://www.onlineaspect.com/2009/01/26/how-to-use-curl_multi-without-blocking/)
- [How do I make an asynchronous GET request in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962915/how-do-i-make-an-asynchronous-get-request-in-php)

If cURL is not available, try to use with non-blocking streams:

- http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-blocking.php
- http://thethoughtlab.blogspot.com/2007/04/non-blocking-io-with-php-mio.html

For added security, consider using a self-defined API key, so the eMail sending URL cannot be triggered without permission. Pass this in as a GET or POST. You could also validate if the request came from the same server.

Answer (score 1):

The only alternative is to not use shared hosting. They don't want you doing this for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [backtick operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837451/exec-has-been-disabled-for-security-reasons-undefined-variable) answers seems to suggest these is not much you can do.

Comment: From the linked documentation...  "Note:
The backtick operator is disabled when shell_exec() is disabled."

Answer (score 0):

Just a follow up for people who need to use shared hosting. While I no longer recommend HostGator due to their sub-par support (resulting from their purchase by EIG), they *do* allow `popen`.