# How can I run a program in the background (non blocking) with php?

Tags: php, shell, exec, fork, nonblocking

I want to run a shell script in php, but this shell script takes a long time to execute (it has sleep in it), I don't want the web server to block when executing this script.
I tried `exec()` and `shell_exec()` in php but the server stops until the shell script finishes!

I thought of doing `fork` in the shell script itself but I don't know how to do that. I just want the php script to call this shell script and continue working, I'm not waiting any result from the script.

I tried running the shell script in the background with `&` still get blocking :(
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222414/asynchronous-shell-exec-in-php

Comment: Or here: [Are there any alternatives to shell_exec and proc_open in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657412/are-there-any-alternatives-to-shell-exec-and-proc-open-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding

```
"> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &"
```

after the script name to the `shell_exec()` php function

Thanks