# Warning: shell_exec() has been disabled for security reasons

Tags: shell-exec

I got this error:

Warning: shell_exec() has been disabled for security reasons.

when i run the following code:

```
return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT (`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email'"), 0,`user_id`);
```

how to solve this problem?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: exec() has been disabled for security reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711675/warning-exec-has-been-disabled-for-security-reasons)

Answer (score 0):

dont spawn proccesses or get the system's admin to allow executing programs

Comment: sure it does. it is disabled and either the OP avoids it or gets the SYSADMIN to allow it -- sorry it isn't better news ;)